# How can I separate my typescript code into multiple files?

Tags: typescript

Previously I'm mostly experienced in C++ development, where including another file is pretty easy. In typescript it doesn't seem to be so much trivial.

There are a few huge arrays, which I'd like to declare only once as const and then use them later in my core logic. Because of the size of those arrays I wouldn't like to pollute my main code with it, I'd like to put it into an external ts file. I've tried to google and include every single possibility, but it seems I can't get it right.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,   /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        /* Additional Checks */
        "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ],
    "files": [
        "src/extension.ts",
        "src/templates.ts",
        "src/intellisense.ts",
    ]
}
```

Main code is the extension.ts, the other two should only contain some constant variables. Sample code from intellisense.ts:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

const completionTypes = [
    new vscode.CompletionItem('text1'),
    new vscode.CompletionItem('text2'),
    new vscode.CompletionItem('text3'),
    ... // A hundred more entry
    ];
```

But when I try to use that `completionTypes` in my code in extension.ts the linter says `Cannot find name 'completionTypes'.ts(2304)`

How is it possible to organize my code in typescript?

Comment: Does adding `export` fix it? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the `completionTypes` to make it accessible to other files:

intellisense.ts:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export const completionTypes = [
  // ...
];
```

extension.ts:

```
import { completionTypes } from './intellisense';

//...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with that small extending that you'll need a trailing ' ;) Also linter was "angry" about including the ".ts" extension, it suggested removing that.